# $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \ \ \lim _{q \rightarrow t, \ q\in \mathbb{Q}} f(q) =g$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

There's a continuous function $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Prove that  $ \exists t \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \ \ \exists g \in \mathbb{R} :\ \ \lim _{q \rightarrow t, \ q\in \mathbb{Q}}f(q)=g$.

Prove that there are $2^{\aleph _0}$ such numbers $t$.

I know that if a function is continuous on rational points, then it's continuous on whole $ \mathbb{R}$, but that isn't relevant to the problem, is it?

I would appreciate all your help.

Thanks.

Comment: What does $f$ have to do with anything else in your question. Typo?

Comment: ... and limit of what?

Comment: "I know that if a function is continuous on rational points, then it's continuous on whole R, but that isn't relevant to the problem, is it?" What about $\tan$ restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Each continuous function is exactly determined by its values on $\mathbb{Q}$. If we have $f,g$ real cont. functions and $f(x)=g(x), \ x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a Cauchy sequence convergent to a rational number. Due to $f, g$ 's continuity...

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt; I hope that there is a simpler solution. (But if you have already seen the facts I mention below, it is not that complicated.)

Let us define
$$\omega(f,x)=\limsup\limits_{\substack{t\to x\\t\in\mathbb Q}} f(t)-\liminf\limits_{\substack{t\to x\\t\in\mathbb Q}} f(t).$$
(This make sense for $x\in\mathbb R$ too; even though the function $f$ is only defined for rationals.)

The continuity on $\mathbb Q$ implies that $\omega(f,x)=0$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$.

---

> The set  $\{x\in\mathbb R; \omega(f,x)<\varepsilon\}$ is open in $\mathbb R$ for each $\varepsilon>0$.

If we define, for example, $$g(x)=\liminf\limits_{\substack{t\to x\\t\in\mathbb Q}} f(t),$$
then 
$$\omega(f,x)=\limsup\limits_{t\to x} g(t)-\liminf\limits_{t\to x} g(t)=\omega(g,x).$$
The fact that the function $\omega(g,x)$ is upper semicontinuous and the above set is open is often used in the proof that the set of continuity points of any function is $G_\delta$.

See, for example:

- Kaczor, Nowak: Problems in Mathematical Analysis II; [Problem 1.4.20](http://books.google.sk/books?id=Xw5T-a-CaUkC&pg=PA23)
- [Set of points of continuity are $G_{\delta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/211511/set-of-points-of-continuity-are-g-delta)

---

Hence $M=\{x\in\mathbb R; \omega(f,x)=0\}$ is a $G_\delta$ set containing rationals. If we show that $|M|=2^{\aleph_0}$, then we have $2^{\aleph_0}$ points in $M\setminus\mathbb Q$ with the required properties.

---

So it suffices to show that:

> Every dense $G_\delta$ subset of reals is uncountable.

By a result of Mazurkiewicz (mentioned, e.g., in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-is-not-g-delta/69454#69454)) such subset can be endowed with a metric which makes it into complete metric space.

If we have complete metric space with no isolated points then it is uncountable by [Cantor-Bendixson theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor-Bendixson_theorem).

Some arguments showing that such sets must be uncountable have been given also here:

- [How to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not $G_\delta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69451/how-to-show-that-mathbbq-is-not-g-delta)
- [Does a dense $G_\delta$ subset of a complete metric space without isolated points contain a perfect set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81392/does-a-dense-g-delta-subset-of-a-complete-metric-space-without-isolated-point)

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Bbb P=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, and for $x\in\Bbb R$ let $B(x,\epsilon)=(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$. Suppose that the first result is false. Then for each $x\in\Bbb P$ there is an $n(x)\in\Bbb N$ such that for each $\epsilon>0$ there are $p,q\in B(x,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q$ with $|f(p)-f(q)|\ge 2^{-n}$. For $k\in\Bbb N$ let $A_k=\{x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q:n(x)=k\}$; by the Baire category theorem there are an $m\in\Bbb N$ and an open interval $(a,b)$ in $\Bbb R$ such that $A_m$ is dense in $(a,b)\cap\Bbb P$ and hence in $(a,b)$. Fix $p\in(a,b)\cap\Bbb Q$. Since $f$ is continuous, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $|f(q)-f(r)|<2^{-m}$ for all $q,r\in B(p,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q$, and it follows that $A_m\cap(a,b)\cap B(p,\epsilon)=\varnothing$, which is a contradiction.

In fact this shows that the sets $A_k$ are nowhere dense in $\Bbb P$. They are also closed in $\Bbb P$. To see this, suppose that $x\in\operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb P}A_k$, and let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary; then there is a $y\in A_k\cap B(x,\epsilon/2)$, so there are $p,q\in B(y,\epsilon/2)\cap\Bbb Q\subseteq B(x,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q$ with $|f(p)-f(q)|\ge 2^{-k}$, and the claim follows. For $k\in\Bbb N$ let $U_k=\Bbb P\setminus A_k$; $U_k$ is a dense open subset of $\Bbb P$, so $G=\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}U_k$ is a dense $G_\delta$-set in $\Bbb P$, and clearly $f$ has a continuous extension to each $x\in G$. Thus, to finish the problem we need only show that $|G|=2^\omega$; this is done in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/81659/12042) to an earlier question, also noted by Martin Sleziak in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

> Question 2, because $R$ has $2^{\aleph_0}$ numbers, and $Q$ has countable numbers, so $R\setminus Q$ still has $2^{\aleph_0}$ numbers...

---

**ADDED:** Suppose that $|R\setminus Q|=\kappa<2^{\aleph_0}$, then $|R|=|R\setminus Q \cup Q|=\kappa+\aleph_0=\kappa<2^{\aleph_0}$, which leads a contradiction.

Comment: I was thinking just the same thing ;). By the continuous function $f \ \ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} f(r_n) = f(t)$

Comment: Could you give me some more detaild about the 2nd question?

Comment: A function isn't continuous in $x_0 \ \iff \ \lim _{x \rightarrow x_0^+} f(x) \neq \lim _{x \rightarrow x_0^-} f(x)$. These two determine an interval. There is a rational number in each interval and there are $\aleph _0$ rational numbers. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Bilbo: have Added.

Comment: Wait. So in question 2 I just have to probe that there are $2^{\aleph _0}$ irrational numbers?

Comment: Paul: Continuity means $r_n\to t$ $\Rightarrow$ $f(r_n)\to f(t)$ only $t\in\mathbb Q$. (If $t\notin\mathbb Q$ then $f(t)$ is not even defined. If I understand the problem statement correctly, the function domain is rationals and the function is continuous on $\mathbb Q$.)

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you mean that there is something wrong with the solution of the first part of the problem?

Comment: @Martin: Opps. Sorry. I've edded it.

Comment: But you cannot be sure that the limit exists. A counterxample given in [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325337/f-mathbbq-rightarrow-mathbbr-lim-q-rightarrow-t-q-in-mathbb/#comment703659_325337) is restriction of $\arctan$ to $\mathbb Q$. (This function is continuous on $\mathbb Q$.)

Comment: Could you say more?

Comment: The function $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=\arctan x$ is continuous. (Each rational number is in some interval $(k\pi-\pi/2,k\pi+\pi/2)$ and $\arctan$ is continuous on this interval.) If you take $t=\pi/2$ and $t_n$ any rational number between $t$ and $t+(-1)^n\frac1n$, then the limit $\lim f(t_n)$ does not exist. This limit is what you suggested to choose as $g$.