# Complement of a meagre subset of $\mathbb{R}$ contains an uncountable $G_\delta$ set

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I'm trying to show that the complement of a meagre set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ contains an uncountable $G_\delta$ set.

Here is what I got so far : since $A$ is meagre, there exists nowhere dense sets $A_n$ such that
\begin{equation} A = \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}A_n.\end{equation}
The set $\bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\overline{A_n}$ is a $F_\sigma$ set of first category containing $A$. Therefore,
\begin{equation} \left(\bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\overline{A_n}\right)^c =\bigcap\limits_{n = 1}^{\infty}\overline{A_n}^c.\end{equation}
is a $G_\delta$ set contained in the complement of $A$.

I don't know how to show that this $G_\delta$ is uncountable. Does anyone have a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Try to embed the Cantor set in $\Bbb R\setminus A$ by imitating the construction of the middle-thirds Cantor set. If you get stuck, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/81659/12042) to an earlier question gives the argument in fairly condensed form, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68414/12042) to an even earlier question gives more detail. (These are both done in an arbitrary complete metric space with no isolated points rather than specifically in $\Bbb R$, but that shouldn’t cause any great difficulty.)