# Are Borel probability measures on second countable, locally compact, Hausdorff spaces automatically regular?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

This is a quote from the [wikipedia entry on regular measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure):

> Any Borel probability measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable base for its topology ... is regular.

Is this actually true? If so could someone point me to a reference where I could find a proof of the statement?

Edit: I should add that the definition of regularity used in wikipedia is that $\mu$ is regular if

$$\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(F):F\subset A\text{ and $F$ is compact}\}=\inf\{\mu(B):A\subset B\text{ and $B$ is open}\}$$

where the infimum/supremum is taken over the space's Borel sigma algebra.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/258407/8157

Comment: @jkn Did you try the references on the Wikipedia page?

Comment: @Bryon Schmuland no I didn't--I don't have ready access to them (this is why I asked for someone to provide one which contains the statement for certain). Sorry for any inconveniences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proposition 7.2.3.** in *Measure Theory* by Donald L. Cohn.