# absolute continuity - closed subsets sufficient

Tags: measure-theory

In a paper I currently work with the author wants to show that a complex borel measure on $\mathbb T$ is absolutely continuous. However he only does consider closed null sets of T. Why is this sufficient?

Kind regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Surely the measure $\mu$ you are considering is Radon. Therefore, it has the following "inner regularity" property: if $A\subset \mathbb T$ is any measurable set, then 
$$\mu(A)=\sup\{\mu(K)\ :\ K\subset A,\ K\ \text{is compact}\}.$$
Since the torus is compact, you can therefore approximate every measurable set with a closed set.

Comment: P.S.: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/258407/8157).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is not directly given that the measure is radon. And actually, if I understand you correctly, inner regularity is already sufficient. I additionally know that the fourier coefficients of $1$ with respect to that measure are $0$. Does that help?

Comment: AFAIK it is easy for a measure to be Radon, especially on a compact space. If its total mass is finite and Borel sets are measurable, then it is Radon. (If you are speaking of Fourier transforms then it must be the case)

Comment: I think theorem 2.18 in real and complex analysis by Rudin should work. It is formulated for positive measures but I think it should easily extend to complex measures, but so far I didn't check that rigorously.